# Using EPPLUS to export GridView1 to Excel - Value cannot be null (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, epplus

Currently I am trying to export the contents of my GridView1 to an Excel file using EPPLUS.  Following some tips from this site and other articles, I thought that I had it except I am stuck with the following error upon evoking the Export via button click:  Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Table can't be null.

Just hoping to see if someone could spot the issue.  Thanks in advance!

```
Line 133:        {
Line 134:         ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
Line 135:         wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);
Line 136:         wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
Line 137:
```

and the stack trace

```
    [ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Table can't be null]
   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromDataTable(DataTable Table, Boolean PrintHeaders) +861
   OfficeOpenXml.ExcelRangeBase.LoadFromDataTable(DataTable Table, Boolean PrintHeaders, TableStyles TableStyle) +43
   Home.ExcelButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Test\CAUTI\Home.aspx.cs:135
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11762653
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6016
```

C# code behind

```
    protected void ExcelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridData.xlsx");

    DataTable dt = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
    using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
     ExcelWorksheet wsDt = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
     wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);
     wsDt.Cells[wsDt.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

     Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
    }

  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Which line is generating the error?  Did you check to see if `dt == null`?

Comment: It is the "wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);" line that is generating the error.  When debugging and hovering over dt it does in fact show null.

Comment: You should inspect `DataSource` to find out the underline object type as that cast will will silently fail if it is improper.  See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971367/export-dataset-to-excel-2007-epplus/26973985#26973985

Comment: Thanks Ernie.  Still having issues.  So if I understand correctly, I am (or should be) setting the dt variable with the current content of GridView1, then passing that into an Excel spreadsheet via 'wsDt.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true, TableStyles.None);'.  However, the way that I have my code, the dt is not being filled with data from the GridView1 for some reason.  Is this correct?  My apologies as this is my first attempt as this and I am just starting out programming in C#.  Thanks again.

Comment: What is `GridView1`?  Is it an `asp:GridView` or something else?  If `DataSource` is something other than a `DataTable` you will have to find a way to cast it to a DataTable is show in that link.  What is the object type shown if you do `Debug.WriteLine(ds);` or simply hover over `ds` when you set a breakpoint?

Comment: Sorry, mean Debug.WriteLine(dt);

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't clearer Ernie.  GridView1 is an asp:GridView.

Comment: And the object type?

Comment: When I hover over dt it is showing '(local variable) DataTable dt'

Comment: Sorry, meant what is the type of `DataSource`.  Or do a `Debug.WriteLine(GridView1.DataSource)`.

Comment: In the debug output window I get "Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in EPPlus.dll" and when I hover over .DataSource I see "object BaseDataBoundControl.DataSource"....dose this help.